# How to disable AllowAutoRedirect with PCL's HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, portable-class-library

I'm rewriting my WP7's lib to PCL. I have a function which uses **HttpWebRequest's  AllowAutoRedirect = false;** property. It's very important for correct log-in. I was  disappointed when tried just copy-paste this function to PCL project.

```
Error   1   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'AllowAutoRedirect' and no extension method 'AllowAutoRedirect' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is any workaround how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in your PCL project if it targets Windows Phone 7. You can however create a Windows Phone 7 Library with Visual Studio Express 2010 for Windows Phone:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs

You can still keep your code in the PCL and just inject the HttpWebrequest from the Windows Phone 7 library project. I know it's messy but it may be the only way to accomplish it without having to have duplicate libraries for different platforms.

Answer (score -1):

I've found solution on msdn forums but need to install portable http cline library from nuget first:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
```

Here is peace of my modified code.

```
HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler();
hch.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient(hch);

StringContent queryString = new StringContent(string.Format("login={0}&password={1}", Uri.EscapeUriString(username), Uri.EscapeUriString(password));
queryString.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponseMessage msg = await hc.PostAsync("http://www....", queryString);
string responseBody = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
...
```

Hope it will help to somebody

Comment: The question is for WP7, which is not supported by that Nuget package.

Comment: @Tjaart, the question was about PCL. this Nuget package supports PCL(if  target to WP7.5+)